# Appending BSON arrays in MongoDB (rmongodb)

Tags: r, mongodb, crud, rmongodb, nosql

I found [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) information on how to use the `$push` operator to add new values to an array. However, I can't seem to get this working with [rmongodb](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/package=rmongodb&ei=h1EAUc_SNpHEtAbttYHwCA&usg=AFQjCNFN9MJ2U7G7L4qgqWhNM0oMVKCVkw&bvm=bv.41248874,d.Yms)

Suppose we have the following doc in the DB

```
_id : 7      51005201f8ab44f1690f9526
tags : 4     
    1 : 2    a
    2 : 2    b
    3 : 2    c
```

I'd like to add a value to the array `tags`. Here's what I tried:

```
q <- mongo.bson.from.list(list(tags="a"))
```

## TRY 1

Here I tried using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator

### Code

```
bnew <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("$push"=list("tags"="d")))

> mongo.update(mongo=con, ns, criteria=q, objNew=bnew)
[1] FALSE
```

### Logfile

```
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6260 port=27017 dbpath=\data\db\ 64-bit host=ASHB-109C-02
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] options: { logpath: "log_1.txt" }
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Thu Jan 24 16:42:27 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Thu Jan 24 16:42:36 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52419 #1 (1 connection now open)
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1]  __test.test Assertion failure x == _nfields src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp 1250
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(161)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(109)                          mongo::verifyFailed+0xdc
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp(1250)                                 mongo::BSONIteratorSorted::BSONIteratorSorted+0xf3
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\update_internal.cpp(906)                    mongo::ModSetState::createNewFromMods+0xa3
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\update.cpp(370)                             mongo::_updateObjects+0x15a2
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(573)                               mongo::receivedUpdate+0x60d
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(437)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x626
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(192)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xf5
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(86)               mongo::pms::threadRun+0x59a
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Thu Jan 24 16:42:44 [conn1] update __test.test query: { tags: "a" } update: { $push: { tags: "d" } } nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0 exception: assertion src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp:1250 locks(micros) w:398335 399ms
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT signal
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, will terminate after current cmd ends
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] now exiting
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 dbexit: 
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 496
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 516
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:52419 (0 connections now open)
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] journalCleanup...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jan 24 16:42:48 dbexit: really exiting now
```

## TRY 2

Here I tried using the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) operator

### Code

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$addToSet")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, name="tags")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "$each")
values <- list("d", "e", "f")
for (ii in seq(along=values)) {
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(
        buf=buf, 
        name=as.character(ii),
        value=values[[ii]]
    )
}
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
bnew <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
bnew

> mongo.update(mongo=con, ns, criteria=q, objNew=bnew)
[1] FALSE
```

### Logfile

```
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4184 port=27017 dbpath=\data\db\ 64-bit host=ASHB-109C-02
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] options: { logpath: "log_2.txt" }
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Thu Jan 24 16:43:52 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Thu Jan 24 16:43:57 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52435 #1 (1 connection now open)
Thu Jan 24 16:44:27 [conn1]  __test.test Assertion failure x == _nfields src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp 1250
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(161)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(109)                          mongo::verifyFailed+0xdc
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp(1250)                                 mongo::BSONIteratorSorted::BSONIteratorSorted+0xf3
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\update_internal.cpp(906)                    mongo::ModSetState::createNewFromMods+0xa3
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\update.cpp(370)                             mongo::_updateObjects+0x15a2
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(573)                               mongo::receivedUpdate+0x60d
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(437)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x626
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(192)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xf5
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(86)               mongo::pms::threadRun+0x59a
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Thu Jan 24 16:44:28 [conn1] update __test.test query: { tags: "a" } update: { $addToSet: { tags: { $each: [ "d", "e", "f" ] } } } nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0 exception: assertion src\mongo\db\jsobj.cpp:1250 locks(micros) w:390312 390ms
Thu Jan 24 16:44:33 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:52435 (0 connections now open)
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT signal
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, will terminate after current cmd ends
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] now exiting
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 dbexit: 
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 496
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 500
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] journalCleanup...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jan 24 16:44:37 dbexit: really exiting now
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

## Additional information

For those interested: here's the code that produced the example doc

```
pkg <- "rmongodb"
lib <- file.path(R.home(), "library")
if (!suppressWarnings(require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE))) {
    install.packages(pkg, lib=lib)
    require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE)
}

# CONNECTION
db  <- "__test" 
ns  <- paste(db, "test", sep=".")
con <- mongo.create(db=db)

# ENSURE EMPTY DB
mongo.remove(mongo=con, ns=ns)

# INSERT
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, name="tags")
values <- list("a", "b", "c")
for (ii in seq(along=values)) {
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(
        buf=buf, 
        name=as.character(ii), 
        value=values[[ii]]
    )
}   
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=b)
```

---

## EDIT 2013-01-29

As suggested by [Tad Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058798/tad-marshall) from 10gen in his comment to my [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8319?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=252431#comment-252431), I re-ran the code that inserts the document with the MongoDB server running in `--objcheck` mode (validates BSON structures) and voilà: the server won't let me insert the doc due to an assertion that fails. If I run the server without the `--objcheck` flag, insertion is successful (but that's probably just due to the fact that no validation takes place).

**Note that I tried two different versions of putting together the array in `tags` as my initial code produced a doc that IMHO is not in sync with MongoDB's indexing conventions:**

### (Potentially) Invalid document

That's how I did it above. I noticed that I didn't make sure the array index starts with a `0`. Insertion of this document will fail (see logfile below)

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, name="tags")
values <- list("a", "b", "c")
for (ii in seq(along=values)) {
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(
        buf=buf, 
        name=as.character(ii), 
        value=values[[ii]]
    )
}   
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish array 'tags'
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish buffer
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
> b
    tags : 4     
        1 : 2    a
        2 : 2    b
        3 : 2    c
```

### Valid document

I made sure the index starts with `0`, so this should definitely be a valid BSON doc. But inserting this document will fail, too (see logfile below)

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, name="tags")
values <- list("a", "b", "c")
for (ii in seq(along=values)) {
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(
        buf=buf, 
        name=as.character(ii-1), 
        value=values[[ii]]
    )
}   
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish array 'tags'
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish buffer
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
b
mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=b)
> b
    tags : 4     
        0 : 2    a
        1 : 2    b
        2 : 2    c
```

### Logfile

```
Tue Jan 29 14:20:46 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6440 port=27017 

[...]

Tue Jan 29 14:20:59 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62137 #1 (1 connection now open)
Tue Jan 29 14:21:03 [conn1] Assertion: 10307:Client Error: bad object in message
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(161)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(154)                          mongo::msgasserted+0xc1
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbmessage.h(205)                                mongo::DbMessage::nextJsObj+0x103
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(784)                               mongo::receivedInsert+0xdb
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(434)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x607
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(192)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xf5
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(86)               mongo::pms::threadRun+0x59a
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Tue Jan 29 14:21:04 [conn1] insert __test.test keyUpdates:0 exception: Client Error: bad object in message code:10307  0ms
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] Assertion: 10307:Client Error: bad object in message
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(161)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(154)                          mongo::msgasserted+0xc1
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbmessage.h(205)                                mongo::DbMessage::nextJsObj+0x103
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(784)                               mongo::receivedInsert+0xdb
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(434)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x607
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(192)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xf5
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(86)               mongo::pms::threadRun+0x59a
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Tue Jan 29 14:21:07 [conn1] insert __test.test keyUpdates:0 exception: Client Error: bad object in message code:10307  0ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I am smacking myself up now.  I didn't look closely at the way you were creating your document.  You have two mongo.bson.finish.object() calls when you need only one to finish off the array you started.  You do not need to call it to finish a BSON.  mongo.bson.from.buffer() does the necessary housekeeping.  This is my fault for not reading your code closely enough.  I thought it was your update failing when the initial insert of the documents is the problem.  For questions here in the future, it would help if your examples were a little easier to read.  For instance, this will build the document:

```
library('rmongodb')
m = mongo.create()
ns = '__test.test'
mongo.insert(m, ns, list(tags=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

However, you are probably pasting in real-world code so I understand where the complications come in.  Everything's cool.  Just beating myself up for missing this and sending you on a wild goose chase.  Regards

Comment: Absolutely no problem!! Once I realized I can't fight "constant debugging" in the first place, I simply accepted the fact and made it a habit ;-) Plus: I learned a whole lot about MongoDB and your driver package by trying to systematically track down the "phantom error". So, there's really no need to apologize, everything's cool. As for the code: I see your point and I will keep this in mind. Thanks for being so responsive!

Comment: You are welcome.  I am glad the effort was 'productive' for you, but I think you are letting me off easy!  :)  Cheers

Comment: One question though: for the sake of robustness, wouldn't it make sense to implement a "do I actually need to do something" check within `mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object()` in order to avoid such undesired "multiple" object terminations that result in corrupted BSONs? Or isn't that possible due to the nature of the buffer object (I guess it involves some sort of (C) pointer constructs which I'm not really familiar with)?

Comment: This is a deficiency in mongo-c-driver.  It's bson_append_finish_object() should return an error code and not append anything if you are not in a subobject or array.  I'll fix it up and do a pull request there.  However, it will be sometime before I update my drivers.  There have been quite a few changes to mongo-c-driver lately and I'll have to get in sync when I do a 'major' update (eventually).

Comment: Ah, I see. Tackled from the other side: is there a way to conduct whatever happens when running the server with `--objcheck` within R? That is, explicitly validate a given BSON doc before passing it to the server?

Comment: One more thing: as I already said, I totally see your point with respect to "making code as easy to read as possible". However, I made using buffer objects my default because - as you already mentioned - the driver sometimes makes a wrong guesses about the BSON structure when the input is a (nested) list: *arrary* vs. *(sub)document*: consider `mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=list(tags=c('a', 'b', 'c')))` (*tags*: array) vs. `mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=list(tags=c(list(doc1=list(value=1), doc2=list(value=2),doc3=list(value=3)))))` (*tags*: doc)

Comment: Right. Well, most of the time mongo.bson.from.list() will do the right thing and since it's in native code, it will do the job much faster than something coded in R which must be interpreted.  I am planning to improve mongo.bson.from.list() soon so that it will create an array when its elements are not named.  For now, it's preferable to use mongo.bson.from.list() and only use the buffer when it doesn't do things right.

Comment: Regarding BSON validation, currently, there is no way to do this.  bson_validate() might be a valuable addition to mongo-c-driver.  I'll run it past the 10gen people.

Comment: Cool beans, looking forward to new versions of your stuff then! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rappster, both of these examples worked for me on my development machine, but I am slightly out of date running a debug build of mongod 2.1.0.

Since you are crashing the server with your example code, this is something the 10gen people will want to know about.  Do you mind going to https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa and reporting this bug?

Thanks,

Gerald Lindsly

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to file the report.

Comment: Well, that's no big deal >> thanks for putting time and effort into developing the driver!

Comment: Hey Gerald, your assumption was correct: seems like I'm producing invalid BSON docs :-/ Any idea why? In that respect: I noticed that `rmongodb` lets you create arrays whose index values are not in accordance with the MongoDB conventions (e.g. first index value can be `1` instead of `0`). Is that by intention?

Comment: I am not sure where the invalid BSON is coming from.  This seems to be something that is happening on your machine not mine.  So I may have some trouble tracking it down, but I'll take a look.
The array index field is usually ignored (and is ignored in rmongodb) so I'm not checking it.  The bson_append functions work the same whether or not you are in an array or suboject.  It would take extra code and processing to validate the array indices before transmitting them to the server.  This is an efficiency concern and why the server defaults to not checking BSON also.

Comment: Okay, that's cool (indexing)! Then I take it that appending a value with index value, say, `4` to an array that currently holds **three** values (thus indexed `0` to `2`) will not mess up the doc/array, correct?

Comment: I'll try to systematically track down where the invalid BSONs are coming from: OS, MongoDB version, R version and rmongodb version. The error must be *somewhere*, doesn't it?! ;-). A propops: are you using a 32 or 64 Bit version of the MongoDB server? I only used 64 Bit versions so far.

Comment: Argh!  I just added another answer that should fix things up.  As far as the indexes go, the '4' won't mess up rmongodb or the other two drivers I wrote (MongoMatlabDriver and MongoDelphiDriver).  But the server's --objcheck won't like it and perhaps it might mess up one of the other drivers.  Best to follow convention.